# Google Cloud OAuth2 scopes not updating

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-account

I have a SPA that's supposed to interact with IoT Core *and* Cloud Pub/Sub through `gapi`.

First I used only IoT Core. I added the necessary scope both to the app configuration under APIs & Services / Credentials and my `gapi` client initialization call documented [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#----gapiclientinitargs--).

It worked fine, the OAuth consent screen showed the new scope, IoT Core API calls were working.

Now I want to add Cloud Pub/Sub. Again added the scope to both the app configuration and the `gapi` initialization call. Here's the argument to `gapi.client.init`:

```js
{
  apiKey: config.firebase.apiKey,
  clientId: config.clientId,
  discoveryDocs: [
    'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1',
    'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1',
  ],
  scope:
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudiot',
}
```

Yet, when I make a call to the Pub/Sub API, I get this response:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Here's what I tried:

- log out and then back in
- wipe browser cache and cookies
- revoke all permissions from the app in Google Accounts

Still no luck. The interesting thing is that although now both scopes are added to the app on the cloud side, after revoking app permissions and logging back in, the consent screen requests permission only for the IoT Core scope. The Pub/Sub scope doesn't show up there.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The login was initiated by another part of the code that didn't have the Pub/Sub scope added.